# Why function returns filtered boolean array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I learn js and trying to write filter method without using it. So I need to my function return filtered array based on function, which passed as a parameter. And it does but it's returned boolean array and I don't understand why.

My code:

```
 function myFilter(arr, func) {
      const result = [];
        for (let el of arr) {
            result.push(func(el));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Calling with some numbers:

`myFilter([2, 5, 1, 3, 8, 6], function(el) {  return el > 3  })`

It should've returned [5, 8, 6] but instead I got [false, true, false, true, true]. I don't get why can someone please explain it to me?

Comment: You do `result.push(func(el))`, so you are pushing to the array the return value of `func`, which is a `Boolean`.

Comment: Where is `func`?  What does it return?

Comment: Any reason not to use: `[2, 5, 1, 3, 8, 6].filter((e) => e > 3)`? Ah, OK I see you mentioned that you did not want to use filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's returning a boolean array because you're pushing booleans into the `result` array. `func(el)` or `function(el) {  return el > 3  }` returns a boolean.

What you want is to push elements/numbers into the `result` array based on the condition of `func(el)`

Try

```
function myFilter(arr, func) {
    const result = [];
    for (let el of arr) {
        if (func(el)) {
            result.push(el);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use the javascript inbuit filter func, you dont need one of your own:

```js
const filtered = [2, 5, 1, 3, 8, 6].filter(el => el > 3) 
console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: "I learn js and trying to write filter method without using it"

Answer (score 0):

1st You need to return after the condition true or false, Ex. For in your case,

```
myFilter([2, 5, 1, 3, 8, 6], function(el) { return  el > 3 && el  });
```

2nd You need to check wether the values true or not, For Ex. in your case,

```
for (let el of arr) {
  if (func(el))
    result.push(func(el));
  }
}
```

Comment: `result.push(func(el));` will push booleans into the result

Comment: @JeffreyRam yes but true means values only will return in his first case not true.

Comment: A needlessly convoluted solution. The answer by Jeffrey Ram is better.

Comment: @RGKrish183 `&& el` is not part of his input as far as I can tell but if he's comfortable with that then yes, this solution works.